# Differentiating duplicates and replicates

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to emulate the following Excel formula  (in cell L2) in R:

```
=IF(OR(K2=K1,K2=K3),"D","R")
```

In a series of data rows that are all either duplicates or replicates the distinguishing feature is the start date.  If two or more records have the same start date they are duplicates, if they have different start dates they are replicates.  The above formula puts a D against duplicates and an R against replicates.  For example:

```
Sample  Date-Time   Type
4753432 24/01/13 10:20  D
4753432 24/01/13 10:20  D
4753441 24/01/13 11:23  R
4753441 25/01/13 10:44  D
4753441 25/01/13 10:44  D
4753504 25/01/13 16:46  D
4753504 29/01/13 16:28  D
4766622 29/01/13 16:28  R
4766622 31/01/13 9:40   R
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Start date? Or start date-time? It appears that there is a mistake in your example output too.

Comment: Yes, there was.  Comes from doing things in a hurry.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `duplicated`?

```
within(df, {
  Type <- rep("R", nrow(df))
  Type[duplicated(Date.Time) | 
         duplicated(Date.Time, fromLast=TRUE)] <- "D"
})
#    Sample      Date.Time Type
# 1 4753432 24/01/13 10:20    D
# 2 4753432 24/01/13 10:20    D
# 3 4753441 24/01/13 11:23    R
# 4 4753441 25/01/13 10:44    D
# 5 4753441 25/01/13 10:44    D
# 6 4753504 25/01/13 16:46    R
# 7 4753504 29/01/13 16:28    D
# 8 4766622 29/01/13 16:28    D
# 9 4766622  31/01/13 9:40    R
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, that worked well and elegantly - the only thing you are missing is knowing just how far down the R learning curve I am.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a data.frame `datfrm` containing the data and having the column names

```
colnames(datfrm) <- c("Sample","Date-Time","Type")
```

I further assume that you have date and time stored in a single string just as in your example

```
datfrm[1,"Date-Time"]
# "24/01/13 10:20"
```

Because, according to your example, you only judge on the date but not on the time if it's a duplicate, extract the date:

```
datestr <- substring(datfrm[,"Date-Time"],1,8)
```

Make a logical variable whose element at position `i` is `TRUE` if the element at position `i+1` or `i-1` has the same date.

```
dupflag1 <- c(datestr[1:(length(datestr)-1)] == datestr[-1], FALSE)
dupflag2 <- c(FALSE, datestr[1:(length(datestr)-1)] == datestr[-1])
dupflag <- dupflag1 | dupflag2
```

Now update the `Type` column accordingly

```
datfrm[,"Type"] <- ifelse(dupflag,"D","R")
```

That's it. Basically, you might prefer working with the logical type in R if the variable can only take two possible values:

```
datfrm[,"Type"] <- dupflag
```